# How to sort a table created with Formatter?

Tags: java, data-structures

I made an application that reads text from a file, counts each word, and puts everything into a table created with Formatter. Now I would like to sort the table by the number Occurrences per word. Here is my code so far:

**java**

```
package com.example.antonpaarapplication;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.*;

public class Application {

    //Function for Initializing the Application.
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Would you like to process the entire file(1) or just specific lines(2)?");
        choice();
    }

    //Function for choosing whether to process the entire file at once or only select specific files to be processed.
    public void choice() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number = scanner.nextInt();
        switch (number) {
            case 1:
                System.out.println("\nNumber 1 has been entered, processing whole file.\n");
                processWholeFile();
                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("\nNumber 2 has been entered, please specify lines to be processed. \n");
                processSpecificLines();
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid, please try again.");
                choice();
        }
    }

    //Function for processing the entire File.
    public void processWholeFile() {
        Map<String, Integer> stringMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        Formatter formatter = new Formatter();
        List<String> lines = readFile();
        String string = String.join(" ", lines);
        String[] arr = string.split(" ");

        for (String s : arr) {
            if (stringMap.containsKey(s)) {
                stringMap.put(s, stringMap.get(s) + 1);
            } else {
                stringMap.put(s, 1);
            }
        }

        formatter.format("%20s %20s\n\n", "Word", "Occurence");
        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> mapEntry : stringMap.entrySet()) {
            if (mapEntry.getKey().substring(0, 1).equals("1")) {
                formatter.format("%20s %20s\n", mapEntry.getKey(), mapEntry.getValue());
            } else {
                formatter.format("%20s %15s\n", mapEntry.getKey(), mapEntry.getValue());
            }
        }
        System.out.println(formatter);
    }

    //Function for processing specific parts of the file.
    public void processSpecificLines() {

    }

    //Reads the contents of the "data.txt".
    public List<String> readFile() {
        List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.dir"), "src", "main", "resources", "data.txt"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return lines;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application app = new Application();
        app.run();
    }
}
```

I tried googling the problem, but it seems like this either not possible or nobody has every thought about it, as I can't find anything about it.

Comment: [yahorbarkouski](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76606163/421195) is correct.  A HashMap (or, more generally, an "associative array" or  "dictionary") is a data structure that allows fast access... but does *NOT* preserve "order".  Please consider "upvoting" and/or "accepting" his response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with the `Formatter` itself, but how you're storing the data before formatting it, using a `HashMap` which doesn't maintain any ordering. You could use a sortable collection instead, like:

```java
List<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> sortedList = new ArrayList<>(stringMap.entrySet());
sortedList.sort(Map.Entry.<String, Integer>comparingByValue().reversed());

formatter.format("%20s %20s\n\n", "Word", "Occurrence");
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> mapEntry : sortedList) {
    if (mapEntry.getKey().substring(0, 1).equals("1")) {
        formatter.format("%20s %20s\n", mapEntry.getKey(), mapEntry.getValue());
    } else {
        formatter.format("%20s %15s\n", mapEntry.getKey(), mapEntry.getValue());
    }
}
```